# How to get correct number of elements after adding nested fields?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I am using Cocoon gem to create nested objects in a form in Rails 4. 
After clicking on "Add Nested Element", $('.js_slider').length returns n-1 instead of n if called inside click() function.

partial _nested_element_fields.html.slim

```
 .nested-fields
        = f.input :name
        = f.input :description
        = f.hidden_field :importance, :class => "js_importance_input"
        .js_slider
        = link_to_remove_association "Remove nested", f
```

view form.slim.html

```
= f.simple_fields_for :nested_elements do |f|
  .factors_container
    = render :partial => "nested_fields", :locals => {:f => f}
   .links
      = link_to_add_association "Add Nested", f, :nested_elements, :class => "js_add_nested_elements"
```

javascript slider.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add_fields').click(function(){
        console.log($('.js_slider').length);
    });
});
```

What is the best approach to wait for click function be executed and then get the correct number of .js_slider elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cocoon` provides several JS events you can subscribe to:

- `cocoon:before-insert`: called before inserting a new nested child
- `cocoon:after-insert`: called after inserting
- `cocoon:before-remove`: called before removing the nested child
- `cocoon:after-remove`: called after removal

You probably want `cocoon:after-insert`:

```
 $('#surrounding_element').on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, insertedItem) {
    console.log($('.js_slider').length);
 });
```

See the section of the readme [`Callbacks (upon insert and remove of items)`](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#callbacks-upon-insert-and-remove-of-items).